# Remove the white outline box from PhpStorm editor

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm recently updated and reset all my editor settings, I can not find the setting though to get rid of the white selection box when you click on a variable.

[image]

Comment: Did you try https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/08/jump-to-colors-and-fonts-in-phpstorm/?

Comment: Yes, I did @VladLuchansky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify **Identifier under caret** color settings in **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General |Code** - in Material UI color schemes, it has `bordered` effect enabled

Comment: Thanks, that really helped as it was bugging me to death.